# How to bypass custom ModelManager in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on an existing project where a custom Manager has been defined for a model class. This Manager adds some additional queries/joins to the queries. For example a simple get query for model using pk includes a check for address.

I'm not able to run a simple query, as this makes a join with address table with some logic and if address does not match, it does not return a record.

```
business = Business.objects.get(pk=id)
```

Can I somehow bypass this custom Manager and execute a simple `Select * from business where id=id` query?

Comment: The custom manager really should be saved to a separate attribute, leaving `objects` alone. If you can make that change, you should.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton I understand, but I think that would require a lots of change in replacing all the queries using objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it two ways, first. Raw sql

```
business = Business.objects.raw("Select * from business where id={0}".format(pk))
```

or if you want to call your managers super class, assuming your custom manager is called `BusinessManager`

```
business = super(BusinessManager, Business.objects).get(pk=id)
```

But as a [good practice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets) you should never overwrite the normal `objects` attribute, that should be kept as is.

Comment: Thanks, this was so simple. I could not think of using super, it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write RAW SQL queries without using django ORM. Just install a library to perform SQL queries directly on your database.

You can also try by writing Raw SQL in Django, but it may not solve your problem : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/

EDIT : Well it seems I was wrong, it can actually solve your issue : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: Using raw queries is the last option for me :)